# WebStorm, PHPStorm, Jetbrains IDEs - Ignore JS and MAP files in Typescript Project

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to ignore `*.js` and `*.js.map` in TypeScript project in Jetbrains IDEs ?

Right now, I have a TypeScript project in my PHPStorm and when searching for a file `ctrl+shift+N` I get all files - `*.ts, *.js, *.js.map` Which forces me to select one the typescript file everytime I search, instead of just quickly jumping to file.

Is there a way to filter compiled files from search? I tried scopes etc, but it doesn't do the trick.

PS: I know working on TypeScript it would be recommended to use WebStorm, but I find that PHPStorm gives me the best experience out of their products.

Comment: 1) PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Database -- in this regard it makes no difference between the two (as long as you compare similar build numbers, of course) 2) As for the actual issue -- either try adding `.ts` at the end .. or try using filter in that popup. Otherwise -- not possible to filter such unwanted entries (unless you add such extensions to the excluded files list .. which affects ALL projects and will exclude those files from any operations altogether).

Comment: @Tom Were you able to find solution...?? I am also getting this problem and need to find a solution....Thanks...

Comment: @hhsadiq Sorry, so far nothing. You can exclude whole folders but cannot exclude file types. Obviously you could setup your typescript to be compiled into diefferent folder, but that brings whole lot of other issues.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-ignored-files.html

Comment: @qballer thats a nice link but has nothing to do with the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this functionality is included in my PhpStorm 2016.2 installation on Linux, but I would assume it's not different than in other operating systems as it's cross-platform.

**Option 1:**
There should be a filter button at the `Ctrl+Shift+N` file search dialog at the right top.
[image: filter button on search dialog]
you can directly deselect JavaScript files and from now on they won't show up in the search anymore. As `*.map` is not registered as file type by default you won't find it in the list (at least not on my installation). To achieve also `*.map` filtering register the filetype `Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> "Recognized File Types"` add a new file type with the name *map* - no more options needed - and add as "Registered Pattern" `*.map` (you can see this in action also in picture 2). Now this file type should be available for excluding from search too.

**Option 2:**
You can hide `*.js` files as well as `*.map` files totally from your project by `Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> "Ignore files and folders"` add here `*.js;*.map;`
[image: settings dialog for creating map file type]
from now on these file types won't not just be hidden in the project but also not showing up on file search (Ctrl+Shift+N).
If you need to check your JS and map files you could open a second editor for such cases, but I think you wouldn't need to do that too often, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot, second option is ***KING***